# array_shift from an arrray within an array

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to remove the first element of the last array

**The array:**

```
$harbours = array(
              '67' => array('boat1', 'boat2'),
              '43' => array('boat3', 'boat4')
            );
```

I want to remove and return `boat3`

```
$last = end($harbours);
$boat = array_shift($last);
```

If I then `print_r ($harbours)`, 'boat3' is still there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because in `array_shift` you are changing a **copy** of the end array.

You need to get a reference of the end array in order to shift it.

Try this:

```
end($array);

$currKey = key($array); //get the last key

array_shift($array[$currKey]);
```

See Demo: http://codepad.org/ey3IVfIL

Comment: Thanks for responding. yeah, i realise that, but i tried `end(&$harbours)` and that didnt work either

Comment: indeed. Most 90% of the things PHP do are by copying (not reference). So to modify the last element you need to point to it, or use the original array's reference (e.g. `array_shift($harbour[sizeof($harbour)-1])`

Comment: @Christian I just added a demo ^_^

Comment: @BradChristie sizeof will not work here since the arrays are not zero indexed.

Comment: SUPERQUICK Neal! THANKS!!! I cant mark as the answer for another 8 minutes though :s

Comment: @Neal: indeed, just waking up. Was just pointing out that the original array should be used in the shift, not a copy. but good call.

Comment: @Christian No problem ^_^ happy to help!

Answer (score -1):

```
$last = end($harbours);<br />

//First reverse the array and then pop the last element, which will be the first of original array.<br />
array_pop(array_reverse($last));
```

Comment: it would be great if you can add a comment to mention the reason to down-vote an answer...

Comment: although I'm not the one who downvoted, your answer is basically the same code that Asker has `array_pop(array_reverse($last))` is the same as `array_shift($last)` - have you even tested your code before posting it?

Comment: @Slayer Birden, I agree with what you are saying. You are absolutely correct. I have noticed this very minute but important fact about some core functions because of your comment.

Answer (score -2):

This code should work as expected:

```
$harbours = array('67' => array('boat1', 'boat2'), '43' => array('boat3', 'boat4'));

end($harbours);

$key = key($harbours);

$x = $harbours[$key];

array_shift($x);

$harbours[$key] = $x;

print_r($harbours);
```

Comment: wow, you made this waaaayyy more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @Neal: so, vote down for it? That's my way and I see that you do it elegantly.